# Nuxt Axios Access to XMLHttpRequest error - not call .NET webAPi from origin

Tags: vue.js, http, asp.net-web-api, axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to make a simple request to a Localhost API via nuxt axios, however, it always gives this error regardless of what I try to do in the nuxt configuration file:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://localhost:44309/api/api/usuarios/login' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I'm making the request like this:

```js
const data= await this.$axios.$post(
        'https://localhost:44309/api/usuarios/login',
        loginObject
      )
```

And this is my nuxt.config.js:

```js
publicRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: 'https://localhost:44309/api'
    }
  },

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    baseUrl: 'https://localhost:44309/api',
    proxyHeaders: false,
    credentials: false
  },

  proxy: {
    '/api/': { target: 'https://localhost:44309/api', pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '' }, changeOrigin: true }
  }
```

As you can see I've tried n things and nothing worked, I don't understand anymore. On my .NET webApi server I've already added services.Cors() in configure, nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a CORS issue, so it should be fixed on the backend and not the front-end.

Your Nuxt app is the client doing a `POST` request here. This kind of thing may be somewhat hacked via a proxy (pretty ugly solution) it but if you have access to the backend, add the CORS headers there (whitelist your dev and production IP mainly) and you should be good.

For more details on what this actually is (security essentially), Google will have a lot of content about this.

Comment: But when I try to make a request through Postman or something like that, everything goes fine.

Comment: I've already added Cors to my .net web api service

Comment: Yeah, this is totally normal that Postman is working. Still a CORS issue. You probably miss-configured it in some way. Maybe create a new question with your .net configuration. This is not an error coming from your code on the Nuxt side at least. @lukecross

Answer (score 1):

If someone goes through the same thing as me, know that what is happening is most likely with Cors, as the friend above mentioned.

You must create a Cors in your Configuration method (in Startup.cs) and use your Cors in the Configure method. Also, UseCors needs to be in the middle of app.UseRouting and app.UseEndpoints (that's what was wrong with mine, basically).

Here's how to implement the basic Cors:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   app.UseRouting();
   app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints);
}
```